# Can't configure a dual boot in Lenovo G40-80

Tags: multi-boot, grub2, lenovo-laptop

Hey guys I'm trying to make a dual boot in my lenovo, but I can't make grub works at all!

I already tried to use boot-repair three times with no success, all the times the grub start with a simple grub bash (GNU GRUB version 2.02-beta2-9). I already enter in windows and change the Window bootloader using the bcedit /set {bootmgr} path \EFI\grub\shimx64.efi but don't work too.

This is the output of my boot-repair: http://paste2.org/BI0yJts1

Answer (score 0):

Well I found the answer here: https://elementaryos.stackexchange.com/questions/1776/how-can-i-fix-a-secure-boot-failing-to-grub-when-i-installed-0-3-1

The was copy the working boot file:

`cd /boot/efi/EFI/grub
sudo cp grubx64.efi grubx64.efi.backup
sudo rm grubx64.efi
sudo cp /boot/grub/x86_64-efi/grub.efi /boot/efi/EFI/grub/grubx64.efi`

And done!